# Modifying objects in returnCallback() of PHPUnit Mocks

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to mock a method of a class and execute a callback which modifies the object given as parameter (using PHP 5.3 with PHPUnit 3.5.5).

Let´s say I have the following class:

```
class A
{
  function foobar($object) 
  {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

And this setup code:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('A')->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->any())->method('foobar')->will(
  $this->returnCallback(function($object) {
    $object->property = something;
  }));
```

For some reason the object does not get modified. On `var_dump`ing `$object` I see it is the right object. Could it be that the object gets passed by value? How can I configure the mock to receive a reference?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

He Alex,

i talked to Sebastian (the phpunit creator) about that problem and yes: The argument gets `clone`ed before it is passed to the callback.

From the top of my head i can't offer you any workaround but i choose to answer anyway to at least tell you that you are doing nothing wrong and that this is expected behavior.

To quote Sebastians comment on IRC on why it clones the argument:

> It's a long-going debate between me, myself, and users of PHPUnit whether or not this is right ;-)

To have something copy/pasteable:

Assertion 3 in this codesample will fail. (The variable is only changed in the returned object)

```
<?php
class A
{
    function foobar($o)
    {
        $o->x = mt_rand(5, 100);
    }
}

class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('A');
        $mock->expects($this->any())
             ->method('foobar')
             ->will($this->returnCallback(function($o) { $o->x = 2; return $o; }));

        $o = new StdClass;
        $o->x = 1;

        $this->assertEquals(1, $o->x);
        $return = $mock->foobar($o);

        $this->assertEquals(2, $return->x);
        $this->assertEquals(2, $o->x);
    }
}
```

---

Update:

Starting with PHPUnit 3.7 the cloning can be turned off. See the last argument off:

```
public function getMock(
    $originalClassName, 
    $methods = array(), 
    array $arguments = array(), 
    $mockClassName = '', 
    $callOriginalConstructor = TRUE, 
    $callOriginalClone = TRUE, 
    $callAutoload = TRUE, 
    $cloneArguments = FALSE
);
```

It might even be off by default :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and well researched response! Even though I now have to think of another way to test my situation it is good to know that this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

The class that performs the cloning of the parameters passed to the mocked method is `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Invocation_Static`. Looking at `cloneObject()` you can see that it will return the original object if the parameter's class's `__clone()` method is not public.

If you have control over the class of the parameters objects *and* you don't need to ever clone them yourself, you can add a private empty `__clone()` method.

Comment: That trick doesn't look very nice, but it worked for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is really old, but it came up at the top of a search and pointed me in the right direction, so worth updating.  Since PHPUnit 6.0, use `disableArgumentCloning()`, like so:

```
return $this->getMockBuilder('A')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->disableArgumentCloning()
    ->setMethods(array('foobar'))
    ->getMock()
;
```