# How to mock a function that variable be passed by reference with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, pass-by-reference

My code looks something like:

```php
class A
{
    function foo(&$a, $b)
    {
        if ($a == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $a = $b + 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    function foo1($a, $b)
    {
        $a = new A;
        $a->foo($a, $b);
        if ($a == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        echo $a;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I need to get the value of `$a`.
How to mock the function `foo()`?

Comment: Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524812/1743367 will help?

Answer (score 1):

[PHPUnit clones the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702132/modifying-objects-in-returncallback-of-phpunit-mocks) before passing them to the mocked method. There's no work-around for primitive arguments, but for objects you can [add a non-public `__clone` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809221/285873) to block this behavior.