# Test Doctrine flushed entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I want to unittest my service class which saves 2 entities.
Only the test fails because the person entity do not get an ID from the entityManager because it is mocked.

Is there a way to update the person object after flush is called for the first time.

```
class Foo
{

    ...

    public function save()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $person = new Person();
        $person->setName('Dude');

        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();

        $user = new User();
        $user->setPersonId($person->getId());
        $user->setEmail('dude@example.com');

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }   
}

class FooTest
{

    ...

    public function testSave_UserIsSaved()
    {
        $person = new Person();
        $person->setName('dude');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setPersonId(4); // <-- this is where it gets wrong
        $user->setEmail('dude@example.com');


        $person = array(
            'name' => 'Dude',
        );

        $user = array(
            'person_id' => 3,
            'email'     => 'dude@example.com',
        );

        $emMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                       ->setMethods(array('persist', 'flush'))
                       ->getMock();

        $emMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
               ->method('persist')
               ->with(
                    $this->logicalOr(
                        $this->equalTo($person),
                        $this->equalTo($user)
                    )
               );

        $emMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
               ->method('flush');

        $foo = new Foo($emMock);
        $foo->save();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `returnCallback` function to act on the passed object ([Some example here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)).

Practically you can tell to the persist mocked method to do some stuff on the object, as example, a working solutions based on your example:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testSave_UserIsSaved()
    {
        $person = new Person();
        $person->setName('Dude');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setPersonId(4); // <-- this is where it gets wrong
        $user->setEmail('dude@example.com');

        $emMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->setMethods(array('persist', 'flush'))
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock()
        ;

        $emMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('persist')
            ->with(
                $this->logicalOr(
                    $this->equalTo($person),
                    $this->equalTo($user)
                )
            )
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function($o) {
                if ($o instanceof \Acme\DemoBundle\Model\Person){
                    $o->setId(4);
                }
            }));



        $emMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('flush');

        $foo = new Foo($emMock);
        $foo->save();

    }
```

Tested with PHPUnit 4.3.5, for some tips check [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702132/modifying-objects-in-returncallback-of-phpunit-mocks)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something similar before, without success. I will test your example when i'm at home again.

Comment: Hi @WitteStier you are welcome! Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I was only able to test this when i did not use the with assertion because the person model was updated before it was tested.

    $emMock
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('persist')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($o)
                  {  if ($o instanceof $person)
                      {
                          $->setId(4);
} }))

Answer (score 1):

A couple points, main question first: if you are testing class `Foo` then all other complex dependencies should be [mocked](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) as this allows you to test the unit in isolation hence 'unit' testing.

If you create a factory class to create a `Person` from parameters, and pass this as a dependency to class `Foo` in your main application, then in your test suite you can pass in a Mock of this factory that will give you a `Person` with a pre initialized Id. Better still, if you want to avoid erroneous test results from the fact that `Person` will already have an Id before being flushed, is make the mock factory return a mock `Person`. You can then stub the mock's getId method with a callback that will only return non-null when the mock of `EntityManager`'s flush method has been called.

Aside from this, I would recommend that you change your model slightly: if a `Person` is always required for a `User`, then require it as a Type-hinted parameter to the constructor, along with any other initially required dependencies. This way, you can abstract the relation between `User` and `Person` with an [association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) or directly by Id but *your `Foo` class doesn't need to know which*

Comment: Thanks for your answare. This is just a simple example of my problem. i have mocked all my dependencies exept the models. Person and User are just for example. I dont want to add the models to a factory because there are to many models and this will messup my config.